# Potential Leak of an Object while using CGGraphics in a Loop

Tags: memory-leaks, core-graphics, analyzer, cg

I don't get it, how to solve the problem?
I used "analyze" cause my program crashes due memory problems and the first one of seven similar notations is "Potential Leak of an Object stored into signalline" conected to CGContextStrokePath(signalContext);

```
- (void)drawHorizoLines{
for(int i = 1; i < self.frame.size.width/_sw;i++){
    CGContextRef signalContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGMutablePathRef signalLine = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(signalContext, 0.4); //LineWidth
    CGContextBeginPath(signalContext);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(signalContext, [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor);
    CGPathMoveToPoint(signalLine, 0, 0, i*_rowHeigth + _sbd/2);//Startpoint
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(signalLine, 0, self.frame.size.width, i*_rowHeigth + _sbd/2);
    CGContextAddPath(signalContext, signalLine);

    //CGContextClosePath(signalLine); didnt work
    CGContextStrokePath(signalContext);
    //CGContextRelease(signalContext); didnt work
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CoreFoundation Ownership Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html), you are the owner of `signalLine`, which came from a `Create` function. You must call `CFRelease(signalLine)` to release it.

The safest way to do this is to ensure it is not NULL first:

`if (signalLine) CFRelease(signalLine);`

Comment: great! ty for fast solution